# Long time waiting Request to Service Worker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-performance, sw-precache

I have noticed that the time waiting for service workers to respond with items from the cache is not as fast as you would expect it to be. I have seen the same wait times with both `sw-precache` and a custom written service worker.

[image: Request to ServiceWorker]

What are the possible causes for this wait time time and how could I reduce it?

My `fetch` event on the custom service worker looks like:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }
            return fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Is there a significant amount of content cached?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. On one application I have 6 items, on another 14 items. I also noticed the same on the [ifixit app](https://ifixit-pwa.appspot.com/) when retrieving images but now am unable to replicate it.

Comment: I would guess that it's either a bug in Chrome or performance constraints on your computer.

Comment: Do you found a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem here. Do you found a solution?

Comment: @RogerSampaio I am unable to replicate this any longer. I am not aware of having changed anything from my end but the problem no longer exists. If you send me a URL I could try take a look.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal

Answer (score 7):

Do you have 'Update on reload' checked within your Chrome Dev Tools under the Application -> Service Worker tab?

If so then I think this may be the problem as it'll be re-running all your Service Worker code, which can be quite a lot of code when using `sw-precache`, on each reload.

Comment: No, this is not the case. 'Update on reload' is unchecked.

Comment: This was the case in my app. I had `Disable Cache` checked, which made the service worker take a long time. When I disabled it, things came back to normal.

Comment: This did'nt solved my problem either. It's taking one minute to load a page even with "disbale cache" disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Event though I can't answer the possible causes for this strange wait time, I do know how to reduce it.

We are able to intercept a fetch event in service worker with event.respondWith(). Somehow, in my case, when my page needs to load a vendor's javascript via script tag with my service worker defaults to intercept every fetch event to perform cache-then-network (for assets) or network-only (for data fetching) like this:

```
if (shouldLoadOfflinePage) {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(cacheManager.fromCache(new Request(offlinePage)));
} else if (shouldFromCache) {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(cacheManager.fromCache(fetchEvent.request));
} else {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(fetch(fetchEvent.request));
}
```

The last block intercepts a network-only request which is pretty unnecessary to do. This unnecessary block somehow causes a blocking load (but I don't know what blocks it):

[long request to serviceworker wait time: ~400ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReoNq.png)

So I decided not to intercept unnecessary fetch-interception (of course by removing the last block):

```
if (shouldLoadOfflinePage) {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(cacheManager.fromCache(new Request(offlinePage)));
} else if (shouldFromCache) {
    fetchEvent.respondWith(cacheManager.fromCache(fetchEvent.request));
}
```

Then my page needs only 16ms to load the aforementioned file.

Hope this will help

Comment: How do you set the "shouldLoadOfflinePage" and "shouldFromCache" variables? This code is on the fetch event os the service worker js?

Answer (score 0):

clear out the indexedDB will help to reduce the time it takes to "Request to Service Worker". You could delete it by js:

```
indexedDB.deleteDatabase(location.host);
```

or do it manually:

> /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application
>   Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB/